# iOS Objective-C float ranges

Tags: ios, objective-c, floating-point

I have a question about CGRect ranges

I need to save huge numbers in CGRect. I have a float declaration:

```
float xLowerValue = ((self.bounds.size.width - lowerHandleWidth) * (_lowerValue - _minimumValue) / (_maximumValue - _minimumValue))+(lowerHandleWidth/2.0f);
```

Its values are:

```
2015-05-21 17:10:01.967 ILG-Scouting Munster[5751:184222] self.bounds.size.width = 300;
2015-05-21 17:10:01.967 ILG-Scouting Munster[5751:184222] lowerHandleWidth = 0;
2015-05-21 17:10:01.968 ILG-Scouting Munster[5751:184222] _lowerValue = 100;
2015-05-21 17:10:01.968 ILG-Scouting Munster[5751:184222] _minimumValue = 4.547124e+08;
2015-05-21 17:10:01.968 ILG-Scouting Munster[5751:184222] _maximumValue = 4.547124e+08;
```

With these values I get `xLowerValue` value equal to `-Inf`

How can I avoid this?

Comment: To avoid this don't divide at zero.

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure you never divide by zero
2. According to [this page](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/objective_c/objective_c_data_types.htm), the values are like below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your min and max values are the same therefore you end up dividing by zero. Dividing by 0 gives the result of `Inf` (Infinity).

Fix the problem by properly initializing your `_minimumValue` and `_maximumValue` so they have proper and different values.